# Problems with JobScheduler - JobsService firing multiple times

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm trying to do some background work in my android application. As the web suggested I'm using `JobScheduler` to do so.

The jobs are sometimes firing **5-15 times** instead of once. Sometimes they are never firing. 
My testdevices run on 5.1.1 and 7.0. The one with Nougat fires way less then the one with lollipop.

This is how I enable my jobs (the 5 seconds interval is only for test purpose):

```
fun enableTasks() {
    val jobScheduler = App.getContext().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

    if (PreferenceDao.getInstance().shouldUpdateJob()) jobScheduler.cancelAll()

    scheduleJob(jobScheduler, MoniInfoJob.getJob())
    scheduleJob(jobScheduler, QueueJob.getJob())
    scheduleJob(jobScheduler, MontageOrderUpdateJob.getJob())

    PreferenceDao.getInstance().setJobUpdated()
}

private fun scheduleJob(jobScheduler: JobScheduler, jobInfo: JobInfo) {
    val jobExists = jobScheduler.allPendingJobs.any { it.id == jobInfo.id }
    if (!jobExists) jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
}
```

All three jobs look kind of the same so I only post one:

The `JobService`

```
class QueueJob : JobService() {

override fun onStartJob(jobParameters: JobParameters?): Boolean {
    val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
            unregisterBroadcastReceiver(this)
            jobFinished(jobParameters, false)
        }
    }

    registerBroadcastReceiver(receiver)
    MainController.startQueueService()
    return true;
}

override fun onStopJob(jobParameters: JobParameters): Boolean {
    Log.d(MontageOrderUpdateJob.TAG, "onStopJob")
    return false;
}

private fun registerBroadcastReceiver(receiver: BroadcastReceiver) {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(JOB_FINISHED))
}

private fun unregisterBroadcastReceiver(receiver: BroadcastReceiver) {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver)
}



companion object {
    val TAG = QueueJob::class.java.name
    val jobId: Int = 2
    val JOB_FINISHED =  TAG + "_finished"

    fun getJob(): JobInfo {
        val builder = JobInfo.Builder(jobId, ComponentName(App.getContext(), TAG))
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        builder.setPeriodic(5000L)
        builder.setPersisted(true)
        return builder.build()
    }
}
}
```

And the `JobIntentService`:

```
class QueueService : JobIntentService() {

private val TAG = QueueService::class.java.name

override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Jobservice started")
        TimerecordQueue().workThroughQueue()
        DangerAllowanceQueue().workThroughQueue()
        ProjektEndQueue().workThroughQueue()
        PhotoUploadQueue().workThroughQueue()
    } finally {
        sendFinishedBroadcast()
    }
}

private fun sendFinishedBroadcast() {
    val jobFinishedIntent = Intent(QueueJob.JOB_FINISHED)
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(jobFinishedIntent)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once. My problem then was that I didn't check for preexisting schedules. 
Could it be you need to do the same?

Comment: I do check for preexisting schedules in the "enableTasks()" function